# .htaccess - Exclude a file from redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I want to exclude some files from redirecting but it still redirects to desktop site. Here is my code from .htaccss of mobile.website.com.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Singers/singer\.php
RewriteRule ^(admin|user)($|/) - [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mobile\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|iphone|ipod|opera\smobile|palmos|webos) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.website.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]
```

When user visits **mobile.website.com/Singers** on desktop, he is redirected to **www.website.com/Singers**.

I want to use **mobile.website.com/Singers/singer.php** to copy and manage files. I use **www.website.com/admin/index.php** to submit data to **mobile.website.com/Singers/singer.php** but it is redirected to **www.website.com/Singers/singer.php** without copying the files.

Comment: More info needed. Give us a specific `url`, what you would like to happen when the user navigates to it, and what happens instead.

Comment: @BeetleJuice here is more info.